# Evitar SQL injection con expresiones del tipo 'or '1'='1

Tags: php

Me estaba preguntando que podría hacer para hacer que mi sistema sea mas seguro, por que con 'or '1'='1 fácilmente se puede acceder al sistema. Que paramentos necesito que declarar para que pueda detener a la persona interfiriendo con mi query? Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php
session_start();    
$_SESSION['usuario'] = ($_POST['usuario']);

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['clave'];

$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'asdf', 'aspirantes');
$consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND clave='$clave'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado); 

if($filas>0){
    header("location:index.php");
}
else{
    header("location:login.html");
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);    
?>
```

Bd:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Solución: consultas preparadas, investiga al respecto en la documentacipn de PHP abundan ejemplos, trata algo y si tienes dificultades puedeS venir a preguntar

Comment: Aquí mismo en SOE existen varias soluciones para tu pregunta. Mira estas respuestas muy bien desarrolladas [Como evitar la inyeccion SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 1):

este código

```
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$clave=$_POST['clave'];
```

Deberia ponerlo asi

```
$usuario=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$clave=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clave']);
```

Y ya estaría bien. Bueno lo mejor es hacer consultas preparadas con PDO, pero usando funciones se hace así.

Comment: Esto podría ayudarte https://www.cablenaranja.com/sentencias-preparadas-en-php-y-mysql-con-ejemplos-parte1/

Comment: Ok lo veré, gracias por la corrección.

Answer (score 1):

El que te puedan colar algo como `OR 1=1` es un riesgo gravísimo que se llama *Inyección SQL*. El alcance puede ser mucho más serio, te pueden borrar tablas, modificar datos, insertar archivos en el sistema, borrar archivos, revelar datos sensibles, etc.

Para prevenir esto lo más seguro es usar consultas preparadas. Te propongo una solución basada en eso, y de paso sugiero algunas mejoras lógicas a tu código.

He puesto bastantes comentarios entre líneas, explicando en qué consiste cada cosa. Lo pruebas y si tienes alguna duda pregunta en comentarios.

No dejes de leer los enlaces que te han indicado algunos usuarios en sus comentarios.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    #Archivo de redirección por defecto   
    $file="login.html";
    #Verificamos con un ternario que los datos del POST no estén vacíos
    #y de paso lo guardamos en una variable
    $usuario=!empty ($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
    $clave=!empty ($_POST['clave']) ? $_POST['clave'] : NULL;

    #El código sólo pasará a consultar si hay datos en el POST
    if ($usuario && $clave) {
        $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'asdf', 'aspirantes');
        #Esto es una consulta preperada, los valores se sustituyen por marcadores
        $consulta="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND clave=?";
        #Verificamos si no hay fallo preparando la consulta
        if ($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consulta)) {
            #Este método es el que pasa los datos, según los marcadores ? que pusimos arriba. Se usa:
            #1. el objeto que se preparó $stmt
            #2. El tipo de dato, aquí dos 'ss', porque ambos datos son del tipo string (cadena o varchar)
            #3. Los datos que guardamos previamente desde el POST en las variables $usuario y $clave
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $usuario, $clave);
            #Ejecutar la consulta
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            #Almacenar el resultado */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $filas=mysqli_num_rows($stmt); 
                if($filas>0){
                    #Creo que lo lógico es que esto vaya aquí, cuando se está seguro de que usuario existe
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                    #Sólo aquí cambiaría el nombre del archivo a redirigir, en todos los otros casos sería login.html
                    $file="index.php";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($resultado);
            mysqli_close($conexion);    
        }
    }
    #Aquí se redigirá al archivo $file, que puede ser cualquiera de los dos, según el caso
    header("location:$file");
?>
```

Comment: Por alguna razón no me deja iniciar la sesión al presionar el botón, o no se si tenga algo que ver con que este usando la versión de PHP 5.6. Igual muchas gracias por la respuesta y la explicación.

Comment: @msiul el código es compatible con la versión 5.6. ¿Qué comportamiento tiene, redirige a `login.html`? ¿Quizá lo que ocurre es que no encuentra filas o que hay otro error? Podrías probar temporalmente a depurar la variable `$filas` por ejemplo o a mostrar eventuales mensajes de error en la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Ninguna medida de seguridad es suficiente. Partiendo de éso, lo primero que haría sería preocuparme de validar y limpiar todos los datos que lleguen.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['usuario'])){
 // Quito las barras invertidas.
 $usuario = stripslashes($_REQUEST['usuario']);
 // Elimino los espacios en blanco.    
 $usuario = trim($_REQUEST['usuario']); 
 // Convierto caracteres especiales en entidades HTML    
 $usuario = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['usuario']);    
 // Escapo caracteres especiales en una cadena.
 $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['usuario']);

?>
```

Comment: Tendria que hacer algo parecido para la contraseña? Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Hola @msiul! En principio si. Pero respecto a las contraseñas, tema que me interesa mucho pero no domino del todo puedes ponerte exquisito y estudiar los últimos estándares de seguridad con los que se aumenta la complejidad y por lo tanto su descifrado. (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)